# Swift Advanced - Setting extensions during run time

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to set extensions during run time in Swift?

I got a protocol named "CuteProtocol" and an extension to that protocol named "CuteExtension". When I want to add this extension to classes I just do as follows:

```
class CuteClass: UIViewController, CuteProtocol {

}
```

However I have many of these classes which should implement this protocol and I don't want to add them one by one, I don't want to make a base class either.

Is there a way to set extensions-protocols during run time as follows:

```
let cuteClass = CuteClass()
cuteClass. // ADD EXTENSION-PROTOCOL SOMEHOW HERE.
```

Comment: you can play with runtime modifiers in _ObjC_ freely, but in _Swift_ that kinda pattern is not really common (yet, at least).

Comment: make this an answer please @holex

Comment: the answer has been made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can play with runtime modifiers in *ObjC* freely, but in *Swift* such kinda pattern is not really common.

---

***NOTE:*** you can find more information about this in the [ObjC Runtime Library](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective_c_runtime), if you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can extension for example UIViewController, or other base class

```
extension UIViewController: CuteProtocol {
    // your code conforming to Cute Protocol goes here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not set extensions in runtime, BUT you don't have to set them in class definition either. you can extend classes like:

```
extension CuteClass: CuteProtocol {
    // your code conforming to Cute Protocol goes here.
}
```

## Update 1

Or if you want to have default implementations to `CuteProtocol`, you can extend `CuteProtocol` itself too:

```
protocol CuteProtocol {
    func f1()
}

extension CuteProtocol {
    func f1() {
        // default implementation
    }
}
```

This way each class can change `f1` implementation if want to or use the default implementation.

You can even add conditional extensions like:

```
extension CuteProtocol where Self: CuteClass {
    func f1() { }
    func f2() { }
}
```

so if you write `extension CuteClass: CuteProtocol {}` all CuteClass instances and subclasses will have access to method `f1` and `f2`.

But be-aware that functions added in extensions support dynamic-dispatch IFF they're defined in `protocol`.
In the sample I provided, `f1` will be called with dynamic-dispatch but `f2` will be called with static-dispatch. i.e: if `CuteChildClass: CuteClass` changes `f2` implementation and you call `f2` from a `CuteProtocol` variable, the code you provided in the extension will be called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't have only 1 class that has to implement CuteProtocol. All these classes are created from 1 single place and I want all classes created from there to implement this protocol when they were born. So next developer won't have to know that CuteProtocol has to be implemented, that it would automatically be implemented. There seems to be no way.

Comment: @asanli Well you can extend `CuteProtocol` itself too. I'll update the answer hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer it will be useful for people. However I'm not working with instances of CuteClass. I'm working with CuteClass, UglyClass and many other classes. I wanted to find a way to implement CuteProtocol to those classes while creating those classes in runtime. Reason is: we create all these new classes from a single class and each new class has to implement CuteProtocol. Next developer won't know this. So if I could automate implementation of CuteProtocol, it would solve issues for newly created classes.